# What would be the fastest way to send emails to amazon SES?

Tags: python, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to send emails, via python, to amazon SES.

I'd like to reach a send rate of about 10 mails per second (actually, twice that would be ideal).

What I found is that if I use the python `smtplib` library to connect directly, things are really slow. Here's a graph generated with pycallgraph of what happens when I use this code

```
def login_to_amazon(port=587, secure=True, options=(25, 465, 587)):
    s1 = smtplib.SMTP('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port)
    if secure:
        s1.starttls()
    s1.login('aws_key', 'aws_secret')
    return s1

def send_multiple_emails(msg, number, port=587):
    s1 = login_to_amazon(port)
    for _ in range(number):
        s1.sendmail('address@provider.com', 'address@provider.com', str(msg))

# I send 5 mails here
send_multiple_emails('about 100 byte message', number=5)
```

**Bottom line: It takes 4.5 seconds to send the 5 emails.**
[image: sending 5 emails through SMTH to amazon SES]

Then I tried the boto interface:

```
from boto import ses
c1 = ses.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='public_key', aws_secret_key='secret')

def boto_send_mail(nonce=None):
    if nonce is None:
        nonce = str(datetime.now())
    return c1.send_email(source, subject='testing {}'.format(str(nonce)), body=str(nonce), to_addresses=source)
```

Now if I profile calling `boto_send_mail` 5 times, it takes 2 seconds to send the 5 emails.
[image]

At the moment, I can only send 200 emails per day, and 1 email per second, though if I just send spikes of 5 mails, it doesn't block me, so this is all the analysis I can do.

Does anyone do this in a better way? I need to be at least 2 times faster than I currently am.

Should I use multiple processes/ threads/ asyncio, the AWS SES REST API?

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: Some ISPs might tag your account as a spam sender if you send too many too soon.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I use multiple processes/ threads/ asyncio, the AWS SES REST API?

Yes.

Any of those things would allow you to send more messages per second than using SMTP.

SMTP is going to be slower than using the API if there is any meaningful latency between your server and the SES SMTP endpoint, specifically because to send a message with SMTP, first you have to negotiate TLS, and then the SMTP wire protocol itself requires several steps of back-and-forth interaction betwen your mail client code and the server (e.g. `HELO`/`EHLO`, `MAIL`, `RCPT`, `DATA`, `QUIT`) which wastes a lot of round-trip time -- again, how much time this wastes depends on the network latency.  The Query API (technically, SES does not have a true REST API) doesn't have any of these time-wasters except for the TLS setup -- it's simple request/response -- and your client can probably more easily reuse TLS sessions with HTTP keepalives.

Note, though, that there are sending limits on SES that you can't exceed, no matter how fast your stack -- and you are responsible for policing yourself.  The limits start out small and then increase automatically as SES observes the quality of your mail and lack of complaints and bounces... but use caution as you optimize -- you don't want to overrun your allowed number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried boto3? I'm not sure if it'll be faster.

[The recommendation is to use https, multiple hosts, and multiple threads](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/from-0-to-100m-emails-per-day-sending-email-with-amazon-ses-svc301-aws-reinvent-2013). (see 24, 33-34, 50-51 one user mentions 1000 emails/sec)

You might end up going to a different mail provider who can send templatized emails in masse.